# Email solution on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, smtp, pop3, mail-server, iredmail

I've had a Hostgator reseller account for over 15 years that I want to leave. I'm migrating 10 of my websites over to the Google Cloud Platform. In the past with Hostgator, setting up email accounts with POP3 and SMTP was easy. Now that I'm a noob Linux/Ubuntu admin, I have to figure out how to get the same functionality with my own mail server, or another solution. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a GCP instance with a Cyberpanel install on GCP.

Have any of you guys done an install of iRedmail mail server, and could you give me your opinion of how you like it, and if it's overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish? I'm just seeking the same POP3 and SMTP easy email setup I've had with Hostgator.

I used to be a windows netadmin and on one of my Windows servers, I ran a Kerio mail server, so managing a mail server doesn't scare me. Your thoughts?

Comment: Thanks Christian. But I'm not sure if that's going to work for me. In the past, I was able to setup Outlook with a POP3 and SMTP login on the same server with Hostgator. And it worked easily. Inside of Outlook, I can't setup one POP3 server here and another SMTP server somewhere else with a password... Wait, so can I set a POP3 server with one mail server and SMTP with a different mail server, as long as my username and password is the same in both servers?

Comment: Although port 25 with GCP isn't open, my secure ports, 995 and 465 are open. Couldn't I run a mail server on those ports? Or is there some reason port 25 has to be open?

Answer (score 11):

GCP unfortunately blocks port 25 so running a mailserver is mostly out of the question, *but* they will let you run an SMTP *relay* through ports 465 or 587.

I recommend using Sendgrid or G Suite for the actual SMTP stack. You can read more about GCP and email [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail).

Comment: We use Sendgrid in my company. I have python example code if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just setup [Dovecot](https://www.dovecot.org) with [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org) on GCE and run it with SSL enabled.

One can even add that as fall-back MX for a GSuite enabled domain

... that this wouldn't be supported is a mere religion, but not a fact.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I think I've figured this one out. For just 12 bucks a year, I can have a POP3 and SMTP server for all of my domains. Thanks to the guys at - zoho.com. If anyone else needs a mail server, you can't beat their functionality.

Comment: How will that solve the problem with outbound port-25-block on GCE?